# Android - track events of other application

Tags: android, events, state

I am developing an application where I pdf files in the assets folder to applicaitons internal storage and display them on screen. Onclick of each document I launch Adobe reader to display the document. I have to delete the documents once the user finishes viewing the documents. I am not sure on which event I should write the "Delete" part of the code. When I invoke the adobe reader my app is going into pause/stop state. But if I delete the files in on Pause()/onStop(), the reader is not able to access these files as I am deleting these. I need to delete the files after he exits the pdf reader. Is there a way I can handle this? Or is there a logic to code this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't delete/modify anything in `assets/` or `res/` dirs, because the apk is read only.

Anyway, if you can solve this in another way, you could set some `lastOpenedPdf` variable in the `onClick` that opens the pdf, and later check in `onStart()` or `onRestart()` for the content of the variable and do what you like.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually i want to delete the files from the internal storage not from the /assets folder in the apk. Also, in other words, my question is once I fire the pdf reader using startActivity(intent) from with in my application, is there a way I can track the state of the pdf reader application from with in my app?

Comment: @NavinC I never used it but there's startActivityForResult(), it has some caveats if the activity you start does not return a result. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29